# Reading OBJ from ArcGIS Pro

Tags: 3d, arcgis-pro

My office just scanned a house using the Matterport standard camera. The results were given in [OBJ format](https://support.matterport.com/hc/en-us/articles/115014357087-Matterport-Assets-You-Can-Download).

Does anyone know if ArcGIS Pro can read and show OBJ files in 3D?

Answer (score 1):

An established method for getting a matter port obj into ArcGIS is to use CityEngine. Use the obj import and then georeference the model. Export this as a Scene Layer Package(.spk) The .spk can be uploaded directly to AGOL or anywhere else a .spk is suppported

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried this but ArcGIS Pro has a [Import 3D Files](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/3d-analyst/import-3d-files.htm) tool which:

> Imports one or more 3D models into a multipatch feature class.

With my bolding it appears that an OBJ file is supported but I do not know if this is an identical format to what you have:

> One or more 3D models or folders containing such files in the
>   supported formats, which are 3D Studio Max (`*.3ds`), VRML and GeoVRML
>   (`*.wrl`), OpenFlight (`*.flt`), COLLADA (`*.dae`), and **Wavefront OBJ
>   models (`*.obj`)**.